# External bluetooth keyboard and mouse not detected at login screen after reboot

Tags: keyboard, bluetooth, sleep-wake, mouse, filevault

I have a Macbook Pro 15 2018 and Logitech Mx Keys and Mx Master 3 (bluetooth keyboard and mouse) and they are working great.

However when I reboot my mac and get to login screen they are not detected/connected.

When I open the lid and login using the built in keyboard they start working again.

I've found that this my be linked to FileVault and yes I am using FileVault.

My question:

Is there any way to prevent this from happening without turning FileVault off ?

When I put mac to sleep they still keep working and I can wake my mac by pressing a key on the keyboard.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is linked to FileVault in that Bluetooth pairings are stored per user, not per machine. So until you login (and thus unlock your account) the machine cannot re-pair to your devices. Keyboard backlight settings are also stored per user for some reason, so no backlight until you login. Since sleep doesn't log you out, everything still works.

A related issue is that Bluetooth keyboards also don't work during boot up (never did for me). So if you ever need to go into recovery mode, you need a USB keyboard if the internal one breaks. I don't know how the Apple wireless keyboard bypasses all this, but I assume they cheat and use an unofficial extension to Bluetooth.

If you pair to the Logitech dongle, it will all work as it is essentially a "USB" device. If opening the lid every time is annoying, your only recourse seems to pair to the dongle as well as Bluetooth and plug in the dongle to login (and switching the 1/2/3 selector) which sounds almost as bad.

Hope any of this helped.

Comment: Do you know how it works on Mac Mini ? Does the above mean you cannot use wireless keyboards with Mac Mini ?

Comment: This is a documented issue on Logitech's site https://support.logi.com/hc/en-us/articles/360037899233

Answer (score 4):

This issue has been resolved for me on Monterey 12.3 Beta - multiple non-apple bluetooth devices now work during pre-boot at the FileVault prompt. So hopefully will make it into the next production release soon.

Surprisingly to me I reported this to Apple (while sitll on 12.2) a few months ago and they got a whole bunch of diagnostic logs and info from me. While they didn't tell me they resolved it, this issue has existed for many years to seems like it managed to get someones attention.

Comment: Just updated to Monterey 12.3 and it still doesn't work :(

Comment: I am on 12.3.1 and it doesn't work for me either :(

Comment: It works since since 12.3 if you have a [Mac with Apple silicon](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT211814). Doesn't work with Intel Mac.

Comment: Still not working on Intel with 14.2.1.

Answer (score 2):

One key thing to note: pairing your Logitech keyboard to the USB dongle actually requires installing the "Unifying" software from Logitech (https://support.logi.com/hc/en-us/articles/360025297913-Unifying-Software-). Once I installed the Unifying software, I was able to pair my Logitech bluetooth keyboard to the dongle. Now when I boot up, my keyboard works.
@Jerzy Kiler: The Unifying software was on my Mac mini.

Comment: that's not available for Monterey :(

Comment: It doesn't list Monterey as a supported OS, but it's working on my Mac mini running Monterey (12.4).

Comment: @Yeti, that may be so, but it works because you’re pairing the keyboard to the Logitech USB dongle, not the system’s Bluetooth, so you’re not affected by FileVault needing to be unlocked by password entry for Bluetooth pairings to become available. A possible workaround nonetheless.